# Azure CLI - Blob list command throwing invalid "InvalidResourceName" error while using with SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azureportal

I Am using AzureCLI in my machine to download and list blobs from Azure. I have tried to list the Blobs using Account key which worked as expected. But, when 
I try to list it using SAS Token am getting the below-mentioned exception,

** Command:**

```
C:\Users\22222>az storage blob list -c containerName --account-name accountName  -o table --sas-token sp=r&st=2018-10-16T12:53:16Z&se=2018-10-16T20:53:16Z&spr=https&sv=2017-11-09&sig=d%2asdfasdfewerasdf$#$%#$%#$A%3D&sr=b
```

**Note:** I got this SAS Token from Azure portal

> The specified resource does not exist.ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound
>   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.
>   RequestId:a108a8f9-d01e-000d-6a6c-6b0194000000
>   Time:2018-10-24T07:38:04.5834052Z</Message></Error>`

Comment: Looking at the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch), `-s` parameter should be the name of the blob container. Are you sure you're using the correct container name there?

Comment: @GauravMantri Ya Gaurav, am using container name only as part of -s parameter edited the question as well to avoid ambiguity. Pls suggest if there is anything wrong in my command.

Comment: I also noticed that your SAS token is expired.

Comment: My miss @GauravMantri, Thanks for pointing that SAS end date. That was one of the issue and as mentioned by TomSun I din't enclose the SAS param within double quotes. It worked after correcting those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also reproduce the issue if not put sas-token in qutotation marks. Please have a try to enclose the sastoken string in quotation marks.

```
az storage blob list -c containerName --account-name accountName  -o table --sas-token "sp=r&st=2018-10-16T12:53:16Z&se=2018-10-16T20:53:16Z&spr=https&sv=2017-11-09&sig=d%2asdfasdfewerasdf$#$%#$%#$A%3D&sr=b"
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Note**: Make sure that your sas token is vaild.

Comment: Thanks @Tom worked perfectly after enclosing it within double quotes with proper expiry date in it.